После удаления linux mint запускается командная строка GNU GRUB
У меня было 2 операционные системы Ubuntu и Linux mint. Я удалил раздел линукс минт в убунте. Перезапустил и вместо убунту открывается командная строка GNU GRUB. При команде ls выводит (proc) (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0, gpt1) .
При ls (hd0)/ пишет
errors: unknown filesystem.
При ls (hd0,gpt2)/ пишет
lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ var/ bin Dev/ home/ live lib32 lib64 libx32 met/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin snap/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ cdrom/
При (hd0,gpt1)/ пишет
efi/
Как мне запустить убунту?

Самое простое и самое быстрое, удалить все разделы и переустановить ОС.  Если есть что-то ценное и нужно восстановить ОС, то первое что нужно сделать, создать резервную копию диска, затем привести в порядок разделы и восстановить загрузчик.

Нет, полегче и получше так: 1) set root=(hd0,gpt2) 2) linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 3) initrd /boot/initчета-там 4) boot
